# Solr query is hanging server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, lucene, solr

I have developed a enterprise search using solr, I have developed a patternMatching class to match the query string

Comment: not sure many people will want to wade through your code...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'hanged'? Does it freeze, crash, etc.?

Comment: @home It was not going through this matchPattern method

Comment: Have you tried writing a unit test and debugging this code?

Comment: Post some code/more info as this isn't sufficient to answer your question